# AWS client-s3 getSignedUrl equivalent

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

My client are currently getting access to some objects with [getSignedUrlPromise](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property) from the package `aws-sdk`. The request are done from the backend and the signed url is returned to the client, everything is fine.

I'm now trying to migrate from `aws-sdk` to `@aws-sdk/client-s3`. I'd like to keep to same structure, but i can't find such command in [the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-s3/globals.html).

I'm pretty sure `@aws-sdk/client-s3` is capable of returning a signed url

Are there any (non - hacky) ways to do it ?

EDIT: Relying on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120548/aws-s3-sdk-v3-for-node-js-getobjectcommand-v-s-getsignedurl?rq=1), i should use `@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner` **on top** of `@aws-sdk/client-s3` to get presigned urls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.html). For example:

```
const { getSignedUrl } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner");
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const clientParams = { region: "us-east-1" };
const getObjectParams = { Bucket: "mybucket", Key: "dogs/snoopy.png" };

const client = new S3Client(clientParams);
const command = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);
const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
console.log(url);
```

Comment: last line gives an error, `URL.hostname is not implemented`

Comment: @red-devil I re-tested this and it continues to work correctly with the latest aws-sdk v3.

Comment: Argument of type 'GetObjectCommand' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Command<GetObjectCommandInput,   ..... getting this error..any ideas ?

Comment: @UJIndia hi, the code comes directly from the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.html) and was originally tested on the v3 AWS SDK version 3.45.0. I've just re-tested it with SDK 3.266.1 and Node.js v18.12.1 and it continues to work correctly. Suggest you create a new Stack Overflow question and include your code and SDK versions to that post (and link to this question/answer for reference) then someone can take a look.